# iOS S3 SDK - Notice from AWS about TLS 1.0

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tls1.2

An app I maintain has been using the iOS AWS SDK version 2.4.16; a week ago I received an email from AWS about using TLS 1.0:

> "We are reaching out because there are TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 connections
> to Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) objects hosted in your
> account. As AWS is updating the TLS configuration for all AWS API
> endpoints to a minimum of version TLS 1.2 [1], you must take action as
> soon as possible for these connections to maintain their access to
> your S3 objects."

(linking to https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/tls-1-2-required-for-aws-endpoints ).
I thought the 2.4.16 version already used TLS 1.2 but I'm obviously wrong.  How can I find out when the support for TLS 1.2 was introduce on the AWS SDK?

Thank you.